# Can I dump the UDID in an adhoc provision file

Tags: ios, udid

I face a strange situation.
The customer send me an provision file to distribute the adhoc version to him.
But the provision file only have the UDID of his devices.

I need to do the internal test before this step. So I need distribute another adhoc version which signed by internal provision file -- including the internal devices' UDID

I want to add the customer's UDID to own provision file, this can make me signed only once when distribute an version.
But I don't know the way to get the UDID from the provision file.
Can I get the UDID from the provision file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can:

1. Drag and drop the provision profile file to **TextEdit**
2. Find for the key **ProvisionedDevices**, you will get to know all the device UUID added to the profile.

   ```
   <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
   <array>
   <string>810497198Device-UUID7f157dd8b7</string>
   </array>
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: the file I got is .mobileprovision

Comment: It is binary, not readable

Comment: Have you tried opening it in TextEdit? Even though its a binary file TextEdit will format the dictionary contents inside it. Try it!

Comment: Yes, I tried. The indication is "The document “XXXXXXXXX.mobileprovision” could not be opened. Text encoding Unicode (UTF-8) isn’t applicable."

Comment: Thats strange, its a clear text of UUID if we scroll all the way till down for me.

Comment: I tried to open the file using the different encoding way.

Comment: When I use "Mac OS Roman", the file can open. Though the file still have a lot of unreadable letters. I can see all the UDIDs.

Comment: The default encoding setting is "auto", It's really strange.